# How can I override methods?

Tags: java, overriding

I'm trying to override the methods `init()`, `render()` and `release()`, but can't get it to work. I've looked at tutorials on overriding and have checked the following:

- Overriding of methods takes place inside the subclass of the original methods
- The method names are the exact same
- The parameters are the same (none in this case)

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Game {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running!");
        init();
        render();
        release();
    }

    public void init() {}

    public void render() {}

    public void release() {}
}
```

and

```
public class Loader extends Game {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Initializing");
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        System.out.println("Rendering");
    }

    @Override
    public void release() {
        System.out.println("Releasing.");
    }

}
```

Why is the only thing printed to the console "Running!"?

Comment: Could you please provide an example, where you use the `Loader` class? I think you are only creating an instance of `Game` not `Loader`.

Comment: @Jan Held The Loader class is also what contains the `main()` method. Inside of the `main()` method, a new object of Game is instanciated.

Comment: I understand, That's where the problem lies. If you intantiate `Game` in your `main` method, you will have a `Game` object, not a `Loader` object. You have to instantiate `Loader` instead of `Game`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the Game#run function by creating a method in the subclass with the @Override annotation.

```java
public class Loader extends Game {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running from Loader!");
    }

}
```

When you define the Game object you have to instantiate a new Loader object.

```java
Game game = new Loader();

game.run(); // this object is an instance of Loader so Loader#run() is called.
```

Comment: The Loader class should already be instantiated since it contains the `main()` method, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, it is completely irrelevant where you  define your `main` method in. It's just the static entry point for your Java program. What IS important is, what you instantiate in there.

Comment: Thanks, now I understood it :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use run() method from overriding class Loader object and not from Game object to get desired result.